# How to handle excel destination in ssis for fields greater than 255?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, ssis

So I am exporting data from OLE DB Source to Excel Destination. I have 26 columns out of that 3 are  varchar(4000) columns which is the pain point. I am using data conversion to convert dt_str to dt_wstr but it does not work for length > 255.
I read few workarounds and tried implementing them but none of the below worked

1. change data type to text (convert dt_text to dt_ntext) - ERROR
2. IMEX=1 - ERROR
3. Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\ABC\XYZ.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0
   XML;HDR=YES;MAXSCANROWS=15"; - ERROR

I want to retain all the data without truncation. Please help me with any other tried solution for Exporting to excel destination.

Thanks!